# О склонении названий институтов в сочетании с аббревиатурой ГБОУ

Tags: названия, склонение

Склоняется ли название института в конструкции доцент ГБОУ Московский государственный областной университет?

Comment: @Лолита Алфёрова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не склоняется, это несогласованное приложение, кот. обычно заключают в кавычки, но и без них не склоняется.

Answer (score 1):

Если бы выражение выглядело так: *доцент Московского государственного областного университета*, тогда название университета склонялось бы. И  кавычек не нужно, так как отсутствует так называемое родовое слово - аббревиатура ГБОУ. При наличии родового слова - аббревиатуры ГБОУ название "Московский государственный областной университет" нужно писать в кавычках,  а приложение в кавычках не склоняется.

Comment: Сейчас допускается писать после аббревиатуры без кавычек в документах отчётности, но всё равно название не склоняется.